# Convolution3d Implementation in Julia

Tags: julia, conv-neural-network, flux.jl

Has anyone implemented Convolution3d nn in Julia. From a prebuilt package or  from scratch. 
ML libraries like Flux and Mocha do not have the implementation. I also tried GitHub repos which build a Keras wrapper on top of Flux and also direct import from python via Pycall. Unfortunately none works.

Please let me know. Thanks!!

Comment: Update, I am able to import Conv3D from keras. However now when I try to add the layer into the model it shows syntax error. Here is what I am trying out.

add!(model, Conv3D(filters=32; kernel_size=(2,2,2),strides=(1,1,1),data_format='channels_last', input_shape=(10,10,10,1)))

The error I am getting is "syntax:invalid character literal"

Comment: Well, at least for this error, it is because Julia using double-quote to denote strings. You need just change `'channels_last'` to `"channels_last"`.

Comment: yeah I corrected that. and the model is up and running!!

Answer (score 1):

[ImageFiltering](https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageFiltering.jl) has arbitrary-dimensional convolutions.